# Why does this ftp get command work in my shell script but fail in cron

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, get, cron

I have a shell script that I can run as a certain user to get a file from a server. I want to run it at a specific time.  It works when I run it manually as that user with the command:

```
sudo -H -u myUser bash -c /absolute/path/to/my/script/myScript.sh
```

I wanted to run the script as that user in general cron so I added the line to /etc/crontab which also works:

```
16 10   * * *   myUser /absolute/path/to/my/script/myScript.sh >> /tmp/logOfMyScript.sh.txt
```

The script itself is a basic (I mean basic!) ftp script and it works when I run it:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="myBinaryFile.dta"
hostname="ftp.mydomain.com"
username="myusername"
password="mypassword"
ftp -ivn $hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password
binary
get $filename
quit
EOF
```

The results when I run it manually with the command (above)are perfect:

```
[sudo] password for me: 
Connected to myDomain.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 07:55. Server port: 21.
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
331 User myUser OK. Password required
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
local: myBinaryFile.dta remote: MyBinaryFile.dta
200 PORT command successful
150-Connecting to port 39317
150 1161.4 kbytes to download
226-File successfully transferred
226 2.476 seconds (measured here), 469.07 Kbytes per second
1189253 bytes received in 2.63 secs (442.0 kB/s)
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 1162 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

comparing the log of my manual running of the script and the output from cron, the following lines are MISSING from cron output.

```
200 PORT command successful
150-Connecting to port 39317
150 1161.4 kbytes to download
226-File successfully transferred
226 2.476 seconds (measured here), 469.07 Kbytes per second
1189253 bytes received in 2.63 secs (442.0 kB/s)
```

and the worst part is the last line says

**221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.**

Anybody know why the port isn't called in cron?  Is there a variable that needs to be set.  The port is 21 the normal port and it indicates as fine in the log of the cron script.

Comment: Why don't you just use `wget` instead

Comment: I tried wget but that didn't work or I don't understand how to specify the path to the file because it's never found with **03 17  * * *  myUser wget --user="userName" --password="userPassword" "ftp.myDomain.com/myBinaryFile.dta"**

Comment: You have to specify `ftp`, e.g.  `wget --user="userName" --password="userPassword" "ftp://ftp.myDomain.com/myBinaryFile.dta"`   make sure to try it in a terminal first, and redirect both stdout and stderr to a log file so you can look at cron output by appending `> /tmp/mylog 2>&1`

Comment: I changed the command as you said to do:  wget --ftp-user=myUserName --ftp-password=myPassword ftp.myDomain.com/myBinaryFile.dta > /tmp/mylog.txt 2>&1 Interesting... in the visual output created when calling the command it says "Resolving ftp.myDomain.com (ftp.myDomain.com)... 1.2.3.4
Connecting to ftp.myDomain.com (ftp.myDomain.com)|1.2.3.4|:80... connected."

but in the log it says:

"Resolving ftp.myDomain.com (ftp.myDomain.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ftp.myDomain.com’
"

Comment: Why does it say `:80` and not `:21`? You did add the `ftp://`, right?

Comment: okay you're smart, that's it, thanks I didn't add ftp:// and now there are no issues, thank you for solving this problem. wget is definitely the better way to go!  I originally tried that probably because you suggested elsewhere on this board but I'd missed the ftp://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better off not using `ftp` for anything, especially not non-interactive use. `wget` can download files over ftp in a robust, flexible and predictable way:

```
wget --user="userName" --password="userPassword" \
    "ftp://ftp.myDomain.com/myBinaryFile.dta"
```